# Problems with starting Spring standalone app

Tags: java, spring, eclipse

I have Spring/Maven project with some txt files in resources. 
 If I start project under Eclipse - Application works fine, but when I export it in jar and try to start like

```
java -j jar app.jar
```

I get errors like ->

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [AccessKey.key] cannot be opened because it does not exist
at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:180)
at raceserver.Key.readFile(Key.java:61)
at raceserver.Key.setKey(Key.java:51)
at raceserver.Key.<init>(Key.java:22)
at raceserver.RaceServerApplication.<clinit>(RaceServerApplication.java:15)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:56)
```

or:

```
2018-10-10 14:19:14.249  WARN 8820 --- [           main] .i.s.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver : Cannot search for matching files underneath URL [rsrc:raceserver/] because it does not correspond to a directory in the file system
```

java.io.FileNotFoundException: URL [rsrc:raceserver/] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: rsrc:raceserver/

1. Files are presented in their positions in jar.
2. When I put them in root jar directory all fine. But problem not onliy with this file types.
3. Under Eclipse all project works fine. All problems with stand alone jar application.

this is the way how I get paths in code:

```
    private String serverKey = ""; 
    private final String KEY_FILE = "AccessKey.key";

    private void setKey() {
    ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {});
    Resource resource = appContext.getResource(KEY_FILE);
    ((ClassPathXmlApplicationContext) appContext).close();
    serverKey = readFile(resource);
}



private String readFile (Resource resource) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line;
    try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(resource.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {  sb.append(line);   }
    }
    catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    finally {if(br != null) try { br.close(); } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }}
    return sb.toString();
}
```

It looks like Eclipse don't put enviroment variables in jar...

Please help with good ideas.

Comment: Maybe you need to copy AccessKey.key file and paste in to the same directory with jar file: folder/app.jar, folder/AccessKey.key or folder/raceserver/AccessKey.key

Comment: Resource resource = appContext.getResource(KEY_FILE);//make sure resource exists in the jar file

Comment: I fully convinced this before asking here.
I think somthing wrong in run configuration

Comment: Are you using Maven to generate the JAR. And is the resource file in the src directory. If so then the file is not bundled in the JAR, only class files are copied into the JAR. For resources use the resources folder in your directory structure.

Comment: one more time... files are in jar DEFINATELY(if unzip jar they are there). there and I use Spring Boot to generate jar.